# Why is Candy Box 2 not loading for my friend?

Tags: candy-box-2

I don't know if this has been answered already, but my friend is having trouble connecting to *Candy Box 2*. I have no idea what's happening, but it says "SSL ERROR" or "Cannot display page." Please help! His Internet is fine, but his computer was wonking up with downloading. (Maybe that was the problem?)

Comment: SSL? candybox2.net doesn't use HTTPS that I know of. Is he putting in https:// instead of http:// for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with a proxy, because candybox 2 does not use SSL at all *(try searching for `https` in the [source-code](http://candybox2.net/candybox2_uncompressed.js))*.

If your friend does not use a proxy, there's a small chance it could be due to browser plugins / anti-virus program / a virus / a national firewall / any number of other things.  Have your friend post his issue to [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) *(with many more details than you gave us here)*, since this is not a good place for troubleshooting connectivity issues.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Because, I didn't even know what happened here, and my friend just told me what he saw. I gave the info to him.